# Adding completion handler to prevent result 'nil'

Tags: json, swift, parsing, completionhandler

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print ("Error!")
    } else {
        if let content = data {
            do {
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                if let rates = myJson["bpi"] as? [String:Any] {
                    if let currency = rates["USD"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let btc = currency["rate"] as? String {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                self.bitcoinlabel.text = "$" + btc

                                let btcprice: Double = btc
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

How do I add a complete to my viewDidLoad function so that the btcprice returns the value btc as a value (double) and not nil?

Comment: You can't modify the signature of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Could you give us a little more details? Is this code already inside your viewDidLoad? Your problem is about the btc conversion from String to Double or is another issue? Sorry it looks a little confuse to me. I would like to have more informations to try help you.

Comment: Please post this code in context.

Comment: use `guard` instead of nested `if` to make your code easier to read.
https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rmaddy suggested in the comments you can't change the signature of ViewDidLoad. However, what you can do is to return the 'btcPrice'.

simply create a new function and add closure to it.

```
func btcValue(completion: @escaping((String) -> ())){ //Added Line
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("Error!")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                    if let rates = myJson["bpi"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let currency = rates["USD"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let btc = currency["rate"] as? String {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                    self.bitcoinlabel.text = "$" + btc
                                    completion(btc) //Added Line
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
   }
}
```

You can call this function anywhere by using this piece of code.

```
    btcValue { (btc) in
        print(btc)
    }
```

read more about closures here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: How would I go about setting a variable equal to 'btc' outside of the closure?

Comment: you can not. you must access the 'btc' inside the closure boundaries.

Comment: Oh I see. My issue is I am trying to display 'btc' on both my main view controller and second view controller using a preform segue. Do you have any suggestions?